# undo a substr function on mouseleave in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to undo a `.substr()` function `onmouseleave`? I want to add elipses when the text is too long `onmouseenter`. Then return the text back to original length `onmouseleave`. I tried `.clone()` and `.empty()` but i can't help but feel there is an easier way. The following is my code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var clone= $("#words").clone();
  $("#words").hover(function(){
    $("#words").text($("#words").text().substr(0, 10)+'...');
  }, function(){
      $( "#words" ).empty();
      var revert = clone.prependTo("#hidden");
    //return original text length
  $("#words").html(revert);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="words">
    Lorem ipsum dolor gna magna.
</div>
<div id="hidden"></div>
```

I have used `.hover()` instead of `mouseenter/mouseleave`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the hidden `<div>` if you store the text in a variable:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
  var text = $("#words").text(); // Store the text
  $("#words").hover(function(){
    $("#words").text($("#words").text().substr(0, 10)+'...');
  }, function(){
    $("#words").text( text ); // Restore the text
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a CSS only solution?

```css
.e:hover {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="e">Hi there, this is a long text.</div>
  </body>
</html>
```